# SubSonic SimpleRepository - Foreign Objects

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, foreign-keys, simplerepository

SubSonic SimpleRepository doesn't seem to have a lot of support for foreign relations.  How can I have foreign relationships in my code models that persist and load from the database naturally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FKs are a DB concern - the Simple Repo is there to work as simply as possible so if you have a collection of child objects, you load them as needed:

public IEnumerable Kids{
   get{
      return Kids.All().Where(x=>x.ParentID==this.ID;
   }
}

You'd have to roll this by hand. If you want to "eager" load it - do on a case by case basis.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for responding. I was hoping for something that didn't involve a round-trip to the DB with every access on the property.

What about for one-to-one relations?  Say, for just one kid.

Comment: Just code it that way - you can have a local variable and return it if it's not null - if it is hit the DB :). The nice part is that you solve issues in the code, not by banging on the ORM (thus the name) - it's pretty bare metal :)